# How to enumerate/install/register USB virtual COM before plugging HW

Tags: windows, usb, driver, virtual, device-driver

I have a USB device that once connected enumerates as serial USB device (virtual COM) using the Windows 10 'on-board' usbser.inf / usbser.sys by USB\Class_02&SubClass_02&Prot_01. 
I have my own VID and PID.

I need to have the device known and written to the registry **before** actually physically connecting it to the system. Meaning having the HKLM entry SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_xxxx&PID_yyyy and the respective subkeys added by some sort of a driver installation and not by plug and play when the device is connected.

Is there a way to have Windows create the needed entries by modifying the usbser.inf and have it install/write the values ... or any other way?

Thanks

Comment: you can use devcon.exe tool to install drivers, it is not clear if you have a driver (or at least INF file or not)

Comment: In the meantime, I tried to do this with devcon, to no avail unfortunately, ending with a unspecific error.
I also tried to modify and right-click install the MS supplied usbser.inf ending in a missing signature information error.

Comment: do you have INF file?

Comment: I have copied, renamed and modified the original usbser.inf.

Comment: AFAIK, Enum\USB is created by Windows then it detected a USB design, you might be able to use AddReg in the INF to add it, but it is not recommended